# Erro ao compilar: Erro 4 O assembly [...] deve conter uma assinatura forte para ser marcado como pré-requisito

Tags: c#, asp.net

Erro    4   O assembly '......' deve conter uma assinatura forte para ser marcado como pré-requisito.

Comment: Oi Rafael, seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português, adicione mais detalhes a sua pergunta clicando no botão [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/75623/edit) logo abaixo dela, como trecho do código onde ocorre o erro, ou informações importantes que nos ajuda a te ajudar, **antes de postar qualquer código remova informações confidenciais**. Sugiro que faça um [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conhecer mais do site.

Answer (score 0):

A assembly que estás a tentar compilar parece ter uma [*assinature forte*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad(v=vs.110).aspx), provavelmente para garantir a sua autenticidade.

Consequentemente, todas as bibliotecas importadas pelo projecto têm, também elas, de ter uma assinatura. Parece-me que estás a tentar importar uma biblioteca sem assinatura.

Tens várias soluções:

- Pedir ao autor da biblioteca que assina a assembly
- Se a bilbioteca for open-source, podes obter o código-fonte, assiná-lo, e importar essa versão personalizada com assinatura
- Desactivar a assinatura da tua assembly